# MomentJS isSameOrBefore missing dates

Tags: jquery, momentjs, date-range

I'm looping through a list of dates and using MomentJS to check if they fall within a range of dates. The dates are 08/26/2019 to 08/31/2019. The 08/31/2019 date is not being checked TRUE but it should be.

I'm using `isSameOrAfter` on the range start date and `isSameOrBefore` on the range end date.

```
moment(startDate) // 1567290720000
moment(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") // 08/31/2019
moment(rangeDateEnd,"MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY") //  08/31/2019
```

```
if (moment(v.startDate).isSameOrAfter(moment(rangeDateStart, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
 && moment(v.startDate).isSameOrBefore(moment(rangeDateEnd, "MM/DD/YYYY"))) {
console.log(moment(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
}
```

I'm getting 8/26, 8/27, 8/28, 8/29 and 8/30 but no 8/31...

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1567116000000 is 08/30/2019, not 08/31/2019

Comment: @AndreaManzi you are correct, I copied/pasted the wrong time. It's been updated...

Comment: 1567290720000 for me is 09/01/2019... @Nando Now I suspect it's a timezone problem

Comment: How to generate 1567290720000?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    let datearray = ["2019-08-25", "2019-08-26", 1567116000000, "2019-08-31", "2019-09-01"];

    rangeDateStart = moment("2019-08-26");
    rangeDateEnd = moment("2019-08-31");

    for (let i = 0; i < datearray.length; i++) {
        if (moment(datearray[i]).isSameOrAfter(moment(rangeDateStart, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
                && moment(datearray[i]).isSameOrBefore(moment(rangeDateEnd, "MM/DD/YYYY"))) {
        console.log(moment(datearray[i]).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
        } else {
            console.log("*** out of range "+moment(datearray[i]).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: didn't work :( same code as mine, adding the data to my original post now

Comment: @Nando I think your is a timezone issue, try using https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get anywhere with the timezones so I tried a few different things, formatting the startDate seems to work :)

```
moment(startDate) // 1567290720000
moment(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") // 08/31/2019
moment(rangeDateEnd,"MM/DD/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY") //  08/31/2019

if (
moment(moment(v.startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
.isSameOrAfter(moment(rangeDateStart, "MM/DD/YYYY")) 
&& moment(moment(v.startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
.isSameOrBefore(moment(rangeDateEnd, "MM/DD/YYYY")));
}
```

now I get a deprecation warning I'm not sure how to fix :(

https://jsfiddle.net/nando99/hy3bm9sz/70/